# get value from ajax request to a hidden field

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to store the value returned from a webservice to a hidden field in jquery

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/AutoComplete.asmx/CompareGroupName",
        data: { Text: text },
        dataType: "json",
        onfocusout: function (element) {
            $(element).valid();
            $(element).filter('.valid').qtip('destroy');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                return {
                    value: item.igroup_id

                }
                $('#hdnGroupNameCheck').val = item.igroup_id;

            }))
        },


        complete: function (xhr) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                alert("Group Name already exist");


            }
            else
                alert("Group Name does not exist");
        }

    });
```

I am getting Group already exists and Group does not exist and webservice is running fine.
But how to get the id in the hidden field and display the same message through code behind in asp.net.

Thanks

Comment: `$('#hdnGroupNameCheck').val(item.igroup_id);`

Comment: no i tried your method but the hidden field value is not set.

Comment: Debugging code will surely help you find the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  function ontextchange() {
    if ($('#<%=txtGroupName.ClientID %>').val() != "") {
        $('#<%=lblGroupName.ClientID %>').text($('#<%=txtGroupName.ClientID %>').val());
    }
    var text = $('#<%=txtGroupName.ClientID %>').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "AutoComplete.asmx/CompareGroupName",
        data: "{'Text':" + JSON.stringify(text) + "}",
        // async: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: comparegroup,
        error: function (msg) {
            return false;
        }

    });
    return false;

}

function comparegroup(msg) {
    populatecontrol(msg.d, $("#<%=lblGroupNameCheck.ClientID %>"));

}

function populatecontrol(list, control) {
    var id = 0;
    var GroupName = document.getElementById('<%=hdnGroupNameCheck.ClientID %>');
    if (list.length > 0) {
        $.each(list, function (key, value) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(value);
            document.getElementById('<%=hdnGroupNameCheck.ClientID %>').value = obj.Second;
            $('#lblGroupNameEdit').show();
            control.html("Group already exist.Click here to");
            $('#<%= lblGroupNameEdit.ClientID%>').text("edit or");
            $('#<%= lblGroupNameInquire.ClientID%>').text("inquire");

        });
        return false;
    }
    else
        $('#<%= lblGroupNameCheck.ClientID%>').text("");
        $('#<%= lblGroupNameEdit.ClientID%>').text("");
        $('#<%= lblGroupNameInquire.ClientID%>').text("");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am afraid that I do not understand exactly what you want.
However, from your code, I see an error following:
$('#hdnGroupNameCheck').val = item.igroup_id;

jQuery object method val() should be used in following way:
$('#hdnGroupNameCheck').val(item.igroup_id);

Add more thoughts. :-)

I see you set returning type as JSON.
If Server side code does not return correct JSON formatted data, the success callback wont get executed.

Also As I typed on comments, make sure there wont be any Javascript error before

```
$('#hdnGroupNameCheck').val(item.igroup_id);
```

If you use Google Chrome web browser, you could use good developer tool of it to detect more things. :D

Comment: Also, as you used id selector, you should make sure that you web page has only 1 element with this id value. So let s say, if you have 2 or 3 hidden fields with same id, you wont get confident which hidden element value is actually set. Simple alert($("#hdnGroupNameCheck").val()) just after you set, to see if it is set.

Comment: Also, please make sure there is nothing javascript error occurred before $('#hdnGroupNameCheck').val(item.igroup_id); line.